# I am trying to create a service account using terraform i have 3 accounts dev,qa, production. I want to give access to s3 bucket in each environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

```
I have this in my main.tf

module "service_accout_iam_role" {
  for_each = { for sa in local.service_accounts : sa.name => sa }

  source = "./service_account_iam_role"

  environment      = var.environment
  eks_cluster_name = var.eks_cluster_name
  account_id       = var.account_id
  region           = var.region

  service_account_name = each.value.name
  namespace            = each.value.namespace
  policies             = each.value.policies
}

And 

locals {
  service_accounts = [
    {
      name      = "my-account"
      namespace = "test123"
      policies = [
        {
          name = "deleteS3"
          resources = [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-dev-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-qa-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-Prod-bucket"
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

whenever i ran terraform apply in dev it shoould give permsiions in dev, when i ran qa it needs access to qa and same for production. How can i write a condition?

Answer (score 1):

You should have **three separate** setups for your environments. This is most commonly done using [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces). Otherwise, whenever you change your env, you will be just overwriting the settings of the old environment.

Comment: I am  using 3 separate AWS accounts for each environment?

Comment: @Akash It does not matter. You need 3 separate TF state files to manage these environments, and workspaces enable that. Otherwise, just have 3 fully separate TF configurations.